# Parse include array of pointers

Tags: parse-platform

I have array of elemnts in parse. each object has 2 members.
date and pointer to user.
I make query to object that have the array as a field. How can I include this array that I will receive also the users and not the pointers?

Array :

```
[{date:dateObject,user:pointer},....]
```

I know about

```
  query.include('  ')
```

but how do I make it for array?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will have to fetch them manually, include doesn't work here.

Try something like this:

```
query.find().then(function(results) {
    // get array of pointers to users
    var arrayOfPointers = [];
    for (var i=0; i<results.length; i++) {
        // we need the second element of each object
        arrayOfPointers.push(results[i][1]);
    }
    // now fetch all the users
    Parse.Object.fetchAll(arrayOfPointers).then(function(list) {
        // do something with list of fetched users
    });
});
```